# How to make my onboard USB 3.0 ports non-removable?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, usb-3, chipset

Ever since Microsoft released Windows 8 and then Windows 10, Intel stopped releasing new drivers for their USB 3.0 ports integrated into their newer chipsets. They let Microsoft do the work. I have a Z270 motherboard and the *Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensive Host Controller* is currently removable.

[image: USB 3.0 ports removable?]

From the Device Manager, the problematic drivers:

[image: Intel Host Controller]

[image: Computer Management]

Windows Update does say I have the latest driver. With Intel not releasing any new driver, what are my options to make those ports non-removable in Windows 10, considering I obviously can't remove them without going into my BIOS settings?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77329/discussion-on-question-by-dnll-how-to-make-my-onboard-usb-3-0-ports-non-removabl).

Comment: Despite this not being in any direct way related to ReactOS, I would recommend that you ask this question on the [ReactOS forums](https://www.reactos.org/forum) and/or [ReactOS IRC channel(s)](https://www.reactos.org/irc), as ReactOS is being built by people who are literally reverse engineering MS Windows from the ground up, and they may have some insight regarding what causes Windows to show a USB device as removable. In particular, there's a person there known as vgal who has been working on some major updates to ReactOS' USB stack(s) and might be able to shed some light on your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a driver problem of the eXtensible Host Controller device :
I have exactly the same device and with exactly the same installed driver,
but the device does not show up as removable.

The problem might be a remnant from some past installation on your computer,
perhaps from when Windows was upgraded to Windows 10.

I suggest the old method of deleting the device in Device Manager and
reboot, to reinitialize the device to a clean state.

Otherwise, there have been reports about such problems being solved
by a clean install of Windows.
But if your device is functioning correctly, I do not think that the problem
warrants such a drastic solution.

Comment: Windows 10 was freshly installed a day or two before I made this post.

Comment: This might be a problem with some other part of Windows, not with the eXtensible Host Controller. Why did you re-install Windows, did you take a backup first, and did everything work fine before?

Comment: I changed my SSD and haven't reinstalled for over a year, I just decided it was time for a good clean-up. I don't recall having that problem before reinstalling.

Comment: Do you still have the old installation? Can you restore it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I sold my old Samsung 960 Evo SSD to a friend after safe-erasing it.

Comment: I have encountered the same mistake countless times on this forum : reformatting the disk and trusting the Windows installation to correctly configure the new setup. The same precautions must also be taken before any major Windows upgrade : Taking an image backup of the system and exporting all drivers. I repeat my advice of doing nothing if the device functions correctly. Further modifying of your setup and installing more drivers might only make things worst.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the [modded Intel USB drivers](https://www.win-raid.com/t834f25-USB-Drivers-original-and-modded-86.html#msg43236) from Win-RAID.

Don't forget to import certificate with ".\Certificate\ImportCertificate.cmd" and install with ".\DPInst64.exe".

As there is a [feedback](https://www.win-raid.com/t834f25-USB-Drivers-original-and-modded-104.html#msg51554) that it worked for B250 in Windows 10 1709 x64, it should also work for Z270, which has the same USB3 controller.

Comment: Did this answer your question?